# c# large fractional decimal split

Tags: c#

My Requirement is Fractional Amount FIrst 2 decimal part add customer bank account and others fractional part add in dispute wallet account .

```
var amount = 40.235667745465465
```

I want to convert it 2 different variable

```
var customerBalance = // ??? - should be 40.23
var disputeBalance  = amount - customerBalance
```

How can I do calculate the step marked `???` ?

Comment: And is there a question somewhere? You know, questions end in "?"?

Comment: note: you seem to be talking about finance but using floating point; these are *not* a good combination

Comment: Do you mean that you want to take the 40.23 as being the customer's balance, and take the 0.005667745465465 and store it separately?

Comment: @John u r right

Comment: in particular, note that 64-bit IEEE754 (aka `double`) floating point arithmetic **cannot hold** the value `40.23`; the closest you can get is something near `40.229999999999997`. The answer you're after *literally cannot be achieved*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work fine.

```
 var firstAmount = Math.Floor(amount / 0.01) / 100 ;
 var secondVariable = amount - firstAmount;
```

Comment: for most people, `* 100` is going much clearer than `/ 0.01`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```cs
var firstAmount = Math.Round(amount, 2);
```

but note that this can round *up* as well as *down*; you may want to check whether `secondVariable` comes out negative, and if so: compensate.

---

Another way to look at it is to multiply by 100 and take the integer/decimal parts (hint: `Math.Floor`), then divide by 100 again.

Comment: var floatNumber = 12.5590;

  var firstAmount = Math.Round(floatNumber, 2);
  var secondAmount = floatNumber - firstAmount;
  Console.WriteLine(firstAmount);
  Console.WriteLine(secondAmount);
problem is not solved cause first variable if decimal 3rd place is higher then add 1 . but it is not my requirment

Comment: @tapos Can you edit your question to concretely define your requirements, please?

Comment: plz check now @Marc Gravell

Comment: @taposghosh your edit doesn't clarify anything; if you're talking about the negative bit: I addressed that - look again! at the simplest: `if (disputeBalance  < 0) { disputeBalance  += 0.01; customerBalance -= 0.01;}` - but again, floating point and rounding is not great here; or use the multiply/`Floor`/divide approach, which still has all the same rounding problems

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a string, then it can be:

```
string secondVariableAsString = string.Format("{0:0.00}", secondVariable);
```

Another is:

```
Math.Truncate(100 * secondVariable) / 100;
```

However, this will cause overflow for large numbers.